# Add custom property to a Paraview source

Tags: python, paraview

I'm interested whether I can add a custom property to a source I generate. What I'm now doing is the following:

```
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')

for pset in sphereParams:
    sphere = Sphere()
    sphere.Center = pset[0:3]
    sphere.Radius = pset[3]
    Show(sphere, renderView1)

    spheres.append(sphere)
```

Now I would want to visualize the spheres such that the colour corresponds to another parameter which is stored also in the sphereParams vector. How does one add such a property to a Paraview source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could  manually set the color based on the property

```
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')

for pset in sphereParams:
    sphere = Sphere()
    sphere.Center = pset[0:3]
    sphere.Radius = pset[3]
    sphereDisplay = Show(sphere, renderView1)
    sphereDisplay.DiffuseColor = ... # 3-element list specifying color from sphere params

    spheres.append(sphere)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, what you need to do is to change the color map of the visualization or to add a pointarray/cellarray (for example, with Calculator or ProgrammableFilter) to the output of the sphere source

Comment: All right - that's too bad. Let me check on the programmable filter, and will post any solutions, if I find any...